# Can't start teamcity server due to Unexpected excetion SQLException/HsqlException

Tags: teamcity

I can't start my Teamcity server on my local machine. It is giving **Teamcity server startup error**.

The error is : **Unexpected exception SQLException/HsqlException: SQL error when doing: Taking a connection from the data source
SQL exception: error in script file line: C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\buildserver 45**

Anyone have any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you check buildserver file at line 45 ?

Comment: Whole file is full of  NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error means that HSQL DB is corrupted. The solution is to restore from backup.